# Why is this version of the code slower?

Tags: c++, algorithm, social-networking

For one of assignments in class, we have to find recommendations for possible friends using a graph. We were free to implement this however we wish. I chose to give weights to each friend (a vertex of the graph) depending on how far the potential friend is from the person.

I wrote 2 versions of the implementation, one that uses a hash-table (unordered map) to keep track of how many points each person has. Than it takes the data and converts it into a vector then sorts it by the points it has accumulated.

For example, if we had a friend graph like this
[image: Sample Graph]

So in this sample graph, 1 and 2 is a friend of 0, 3 is the sole friend of 1 and so on and so forth.

My algorithm starts at a distance of 2 (a distance of 1 means that vertex is already a friend) and gives points depending on how far the vertex is.

For example possible friends of 0 can be calculated by:

```
At a distance of 2 (points: 1/2)
  3 : 0.5 (0 - 1 - 3)
  4 : 0.5 (0 - 2 - 4)
At a distance of 3 (points: 1/9)
  4 : 0.111111 (0 - 1 - 3 - 4)
  5 : 0.111111 (0 - 1 - 3 - 5)
  5 : 0.111111 (0 - 2 - 4 - 5)
At a distance of 4 (points: 1/16)
  5 : 0.0625 (0 - 1 - 3 - 4 - 5)
```

After adding these weights up we get:

```
  4 : 0.611111
  3 : 0.5
  5 : 0.284722
```

From this information we can tell that person 4 has the best chance of being a friend of person 0

My first attempt was to use a hashtable to store all the people (vertexes) and their point values, then it would convert it into a vector and lastly sort them by the points.

```
std::unordered_map<int, double> friends;

/// @todo make this recursive
for (auto e1 : vertex_list[vs]->edge_list) { // this is level 1 (already our friend))
    for (auto e2 : vertex_list[e1->target_vertex]->edge_list) { // this is level 2 (potential friends)
        friends[e2->target_vertex] += 0.5;

        for (auto e3 : vertex_list[e2->target_vertex]->edge_list) {
            friends[e3->target_vertex] += 1/9.0;

            for (auto e4 : vertex_list[e3->target_vertex]->edge_list) {
                friends[e4->target_vertex] += 1/16.0;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> tmp{friends.begin(), friends.end()};
std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), [](auto a, auto b) {return a.second > b.second;});

for (int i = 0; i < ((tmp.size() < 10)? tmp.size() : 10); ++i) {
    // cout << i << "\t\t";
    cout << tmp[i].first << '\t' << tmp[i].second << endl;
}
```

Then I thought well instead of all this copying of data, converting between data structures, what if I created my data structure that gave a O(1) lookup time and also keep the elements sorted, I mean this is for a Data Structures and Algorithms class. I created this:

The structure uses a hash table to keep iterators to a std::list that keeps the key-value pairs sorted. The hash table maps the key to an iterator to a element in the list. When adding some data to the value, the data structure will move the node up and down to keep it sorted.

```
template <
    typename TKey,
    typename TValue //,
    //typename THash = std:: // we can add this functionality later
> class ordered_vecmap {
public:
    using key_type   = TKey;
    using value_type = TValue;
    using size_type  = size_t;
    using locator    = typename std::list<std::pair<key_type, value_type>>::iterator;

    ordered_vecmap(size_type sz) : mIndex{}, mData{} {
        mIndex.rehash(sz);
    }

    void add_to_value(const key_type& key, const value_type& val) { 
        // create valuu if not exists
        if (mIndex.find(key) == mIndex.end()) { // new key-value pair
            mData.emplace_back(key, 0.0); // insert new value
            mIndex.insert({key, --mData.end()}); // add the key so it now points to the last member of the vector
        }

        // add to the value
        locator idx = mIndex[key];
        idx->second += val;

        // fix it so its ordered
        // while the current value is out of ordered
        // and we havent reached the max value
        // also prevents iterator invalidation
        auto prev = std::prev(idx);
        while (idx != mData.begin() and idx->second > prev->second) {
            mData.splice(prev, mData, idx);
            --(--prev);
        }
    }

    std::list<std::pair<key_type, value_type>>& get_results() { return mData; }

private:

    std::unordered_map<key_type, locator> mIndex; // this containtains all the indexes
    std::list<std::pair<key_type, value_type>> mData; // this contains the actual data

};
```

And here is the find friends function (almost identical to the original algorithm)

```
ari::ordered_vecmap<int, double> friends{vertex_list.size()};

/// @todo make this recursive
for (auto e1 : vertex_list[vs]->edge_list) { // this is level 1 (already our friend))
    for (auto e2 : vertex_list[e1->target_vertex]->edge_list) { // this is level 2 (potential friends)
        friends.add_to_value(e2->target_vertex, 0.5);

        for (auto e3 : vertex_list[e2->target_vertex]->edge_list) {
            friends.add_to_value(e3->target_vertex, 1/9.0);

            for (auto e4 : vertex_list[e3->target_vertex]->edge_list) {
                friends.add_to_value(e4->target_vertex, 1/16.0);
            }
        }
    }
}

auto& tmp = friends.get_results();
auto it = tmp.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < ((tmp.size() < 10)? tmp.size() : 10); ++i) {
    // cout << i << "\t\t";
    cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << endl;
    ++it;
}
```

The problem is that theoretically, the data structure I created should at perform close to, if not better than my original algorithm. However I timed both algorithms and I found my data structure is a 5-7 times slower. The first algorithm took 93ms and the custom data structure took 468ms with a 4,000 verticies

I'm confused on why?

**EDIT:**
So as one of the comments said, It may be because of the cache misses in lists, so I converted my code to use a std::vector rather than a std::list, it seems it has gotten worse. The first algorithm performs the same: 93ms and the custom data structure took 671ms. Here is my revised code using a vector (just the add_to_value member function)

```
void add_to_value(const key_type& key, const value_type& val) { 
    // create valuu if not exists       
    if (mIndex.find(key) == mIndex.end()) { // new key-value pair
        mIndex.insert({key, mData.size()}); // add the key so it now points to the last member of the vector
        mData.emplace_back(key, 0.0); // insert new value
    }

    // add to the value
    locator idx = mIndex[key];
    mData[idx].second += val;

    // fix it so its ordered
    // while the current value is out of ordered
    // and we havent reached the max value
    // also prevents iterator invalidation
    while (idx != 0 and mData[idx].second > mData[idx - 1].second) {
        std::swap(mData[idx], mData[idx - 1]); // swap this an previous
        mIndex[mData[idx].first] = idx; // fix the previous locator
        --idx;
    }

    mIndex[key] = idx;
}
```

Comment: In the second solution you have two allocations for each element, one in `mIndex` and one in `mData`. And traversing a list is expensive as following links is a cache unfriendly random memory access. On the other hand, when creating the vector it will check the distance between the iterators and just do a single memory allocation.

Comment: @BoPersson I just used a std::vector instead of a std::list, and it actually made it a little bit worse (1st alg: 93ms | 2nd alg: 671ms)

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for a solution, but did you measure the time needed for all the sorting by `splice`/`swap`? It looks quite expensive compared to sorting a vector once. But I'm just guessing...